# Declaring type *big.Int overflowing constant golang

Tags: go, struct, rsa, bigint

Generating a keypair using the crypto/rsa package is trivial, but declaring it yourself is a pain.

I'm trying to declare a variable of type rsa.PublicKey, which is defined as:

```
type PublicKey struct {
        N *big.Int // modulus
        E int      // public exponent
}
```

I've tried a hundred and three methods, but my code currently looks like:

```
PublicKey := new(rsa.PublicKey)

PublicKey.N = 816296297763124917516388440338759500423535395290623239231731567955308683122890408110917894172120047293936355563865250296188045077627313515614945465389856882915690164742049821466713295090362914686221827012330520911241180940331170800129566133563943306086709509374426793735798983196271063876215936717347200817820685489907456621846519078704338901417077754153251584919148131668369473222078960469749879767829241702858598298315759777245767370065542249841401685747514693845945420663931515035586797756896017462499826100826469085345198490755785708882569397123671313993933597159332140624225622926365258472081852103795720495728779491860405409429756519754432759030127289255409541378096471189783136441306888685144178712329637014132885623358066824356187044819578205172698506597932578231190886063535262514544569054747443504586895362356519252402500104155389876467086444850150261677007183689594568339805440756958346151465691221654766132846717117978938197863452998630570321897641091974200100764524637808876854013287571133384735164135339783262769321526997252096927500094807456840263828514476848496064212933462545940124330314474126636272733109787671957872657823289210871868354885730638093964892263227561606744192311648252923260065974092128743259979645799

PublicKey.E = 65537
```

I get this error:

```
./main.go:21: constant too large: 816296297763124917516388440338759500423535395290623239231731567955308683122890408110917894172120047293936355563865250296188045077627313515614945465389856882915690164742049821466713295090362914686221827012330520911241180940331170800129566133563943306086709509374426793735798983196271063876215936717347200817820685489907456621846519078704338901417077754153251584919148131668369473222078960469749879767829241702858598298315759777245767370065542249841401685747514693845945420663931515035586797756896017462499826100826469085345198490755785708882569397123671313993933597159332140624225622926365258472081852103795720495728779491860405409429756519754432759030127289255409541378096471189783136441306888685144178712329637014132885623358066824356187044819578205172698506597932578231190886063535262514544569054747443504586895362356519252402500104155389876467086444850150261677007183689594568339805440756958346151465691221654766132846717117978938197863452998630570321897641091974200100764524637808876854013287571133384735164135339783262769321526997252096927500094807456840263828514476848496064212933462545940124330314474126636272733109787671957872657823289210871868354885730638093964892263227561606744192311648252923260065974092128743259979645799
./main.go:21: overflow in constant
./main.go:21: cannot use 0 (type int) as type *big.Int in assignment
```

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer from T. Claverie will create a public key but will not set the modulus (PublicKey.N) to the number you see. Instead it will use the character codes of those numbers.

```
fmt.Print([]byte("1"))
[49]
```

You can use big.Int.UnmarshalText() to get the key you see in the input string.

```
PublicKey := new(rsa.PublicKey)
PublicKey.N = big.NewInt(0)
PublicKey.N.UnmarshalText([]byte("8162962977631249175163884403387595004235353952981629629776312491751638844033875950042353539529"))
```

You can see the difference here: https://play.golang.org/p/HL6YNdcSubv

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Go interprets your literal value as an int. But, it does not really fit into 32 bits, so it fails. However, you can set the value of a `big.Int` after its creation:

```
PublicKey.N = big.NewInt(0)
PublicKey.N.SetBytes([]byte("8162962977631249175163884403387595004235353952981629629776312491751638844033875950042353539529"))
fmt.Println(N)
// 8162962977631249175163884403387595004235353952981629629776312491751638844033875950042353539529
```